# Flex Mobile: Can't position the component properly in titlecontent area of ActionBar

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex-actionbar

Things go weird when i tried position a button in titleContent of ActionBar. Set both the "left" and "horizontalCenter" can't move my button.Code as below:

```
    <s:titleContent>
       <s:Button label="HELLO" left="50"/>
    </s:titleContent>
```

How can I position a Button at the middle of this Actionbar??

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ActionBar.html) say that the default layout for the titleContent is [HorizontalLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/HorizontalLayout.html). So 'left' and 'horizontalCenter' do not apply.

You can use the `titleLayout` property to use a different layout ([BasicLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/BasicLayout.html)) for the title content:

```
<s:titleLayout>
    <s:BasicLayout />
</s:titleLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use css :

```
s|ActionBar 
{
    titleAlign: center;
}
```